# unable to open xml file from server using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, file, anchor

i Have one xml file in server i am trying to open it in browser when user click on link so i have set link as below. but it does not opening file.

code :

```
<a title="View XML" href="file://///90.0.0.15/docmgmtandpub/PublishDestinationFolder/index.xml" target="_blank"> Click here </a>
```

i have also try using javascript as below:

```
function openFL()
{

    window.open("file:////90.0.0.15/docmgmtandpub/PublishDestinationFolder/index.xml"); 
}
```

if i copy path and try opening in browser directly it working fine but not working through code.

Answer (score 1):

Linking to `file://` URIs from webpages is fraught with security restrictions and variances in how browsers handle `file://` URIs - especially with network paths.

Serve the file over HTTP instead.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. How can i open above file using http

Comment: You run a webserver on the machine at 90.0.0.15

Comment: Actually i have file server in 90.0.0.15 and my application is in other machine.

Comment: The term "file server" is meaningless. There are lots of protocols that you can serve files with. Use HTTP.

Comment: After you install and properly configure a webserver - yes.

Comment: The same thing as I told you in my previous comments — a webserver.

Comment: i have tomcat installed in 90.0.0.137 machine (applicaiton run here ). i want to open file available in 90.0.0.15. any configuration i need to do in 90.0.0.15 machine??

Comment: Yes. You need to install a webserver on it.

Comment: Then you need to set it up so that the file you want is under the webroot (or aliased, or whatever) and then work out the http url for it.